# Similarity of $4\times 4$ matrices having the same Distinct Eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, vectors

I tried to solve this problem. I think I solved it but I'm not really whether this  is a correct proof.

**Problem:**
All matrices $A\in \mathcal{M}_{4}(\mathbb{R})$ with eigenvalues of $0,1,2,3$ are similar? Yes/No?

**My solution:**
We have four eigenvalues, so we have four linearly independent eigenvectors. These four distinct eigenvalues correspond to four  distinct eigenvectors. So, we conclude that we have a basis for $\mathbb{R}^4$ consisting of eigenvectors of $A$. So all matrices $A$ are similar to diagonal matrix $\operatorname{Diag}(0,1,2,3)$. So they are all similar. 
I think my proof is correct but I'm not sure. Hopefully someone can verify this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your argument is fine. You might phrase it more clearly in the following manner: all $A\in \mathcal{M}_4(\mathbb{R})$ with (distinct) eigenvalues $0,1,2,3$ are similar to the diagonal matrix 
$$ D=
\begin{bmatrix}
0&&&\\
&1&&\\
&&2&\\
&&&3
\end{bmatrix}.$$
Similarity is an equivalence relation on $\mathcal{M}_4(\mathbb{R})$, so by transitivity, we get that any two matrices $A,B\in \mathcal{M}_4(\mathbb{R})$ with distinct eigenvalues $0,1,2,3$ are similar.

Comment: Wow, great! Thank you! :)